# Not able to create new Project with ADT version 20

Tags: android, adt

I have recently updated my ADT and it is now ADT_V20. I have also updated my SDK platform tools as well. But I am not able to create new Project through Project wizard from Eclipse.
I have Eclipse Helios latest version. and It was working well with old ADT versions.

In the project wizard I have reached upto Install Dependencies screen, where "Next" and "Finish" buttons are disabled. I have tried to "Install/Upgrade" new version as shown in the wizard and that process is completed successfully . Still I am not getting "Next" or "Finish" buttons enabled.

This same thing happens on the other PCs as well.

Could anybody please help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like you can get around this issue by uninstalling the Support library from the SDK manager, then reinstalling at the prompt in the wizard.  I had the same problem you did, and this solution worked for me.

Source: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859

Comment: This worked for me, however, after passing this step I cannot dismiss the dialog even by pressing Finish, and the project is empty in Eclipse.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Ryan R. I hit Finish but the window stays up, and if I cancel out the project is empty in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

In the new Android Project Wizard on the second screen where is says "Select whether to create an activity, and if so, what kind of activity"

- Simple un-check the Create Activity, A new Blank Activity will be enabled to be created.  -
- Click Finish.

They might push a fix for the issue you have highlighted soon.

I have come across some more issues related to Ant build.xml not able to find "com.android.ant.NewSetupTask" due to this upgrade to ADT20

Comment: Again when we are going through the wizard for the first time , on the second screen , Next and Finish buttons are disabled. At that time we have to cancel the wizard and again have to create new project and have to reached to the second screen. Now you uncheck the create Activity and you will find Finish button enabled. It is  weird  :)

Answer (score 1):

After installing ADT version 20, I have this problem creating a 1.6/API 8 project now that the newer (version 20) SDK is installed.

Would one of the experts try creating this even WITHOUT the 'activity' please?

I cannot complete with the blank activity checked (due to the missing API 8, which tries to install the already installed API 9 when asked to update), NOR can I complete with NO activity selected.

In the latter case, i.e., uncheck the create Activity box, the Finish button appears, creates the project partially, but not one that will build (as the older versions would do even with an old API.

Also, there is no actual indication that the "Finish" has worked -- you must look over in the browse pane to see the new project even though the dialog remains.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the above did n't solved your problem please do one thing, try DELETING org.apache.log4j_1.2.17.jar from eclipse/plugin directory !!!!

Answer (score 0):

In MACOSX, with Eclipse Helios IDE, this solution didn't work for me. I solved the problem uninstalling the components by the SDK tools and installing them again by the same SDK manager. I tried to reinstall the components by the same new project dialog, but didn't work for me, my only solution was that, uninstalling and reinstalling from sdk manager.

I hope this solution works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that I found out that Android Support Library was not installed on my computer (I didn't even have an Android folder under extras/. I ran the SDK Manager as Administrator, selected this and installed it. Then I tried creating a new project and I got the same error. I clicked Install/Upgrade and the Finish button became enabled. The next time I created a new project, I didn't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the app had been created, but I didn't see it as it was completely obsqured by the welcome splash screen. When I didn't see it, I tried to create the app again, and it was failing to finish silently. Only when I ventured to close the splash screen did all become clear.