# Install Dependencies not resolved in ADT r20

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

I just update my ADT and SDK to latest version of **ADT r20** and **Android 4.1** in SDK.

Now in Eclipse i can not make a new project with default **BlankActivity** implemented in it.

In the new project dialog i am sticking at the last screen which mention that there is **"Install Dependencies"** of **`android support library revision 8 required`** for this.

I **already** have **revision 9** installed in SDK. I also clicked "**Install/Upgrade**" button and it also fetch library from internet but after that no success.

Below is screenshot of that dialog
[image]

```
I know that we can create blank project by unchecking 
CreateActivity option, but i want to make project with BlankActivity
```

[Android Issue Tracker link for the same issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=33872)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to open the SDK Manager and uninstall your current Support library, then in the New Project wizard, use the button there to install it again.

See [Not able to create new Project with ADT version 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259069/not-able-to-create-new-project-with-adt-version-20/11262604#11262604)

Answer (score 3):

You need to open your SDK Manager and install revision 9:

[image: SDK Tools]

<s>I'm not sure but I think: This is only possible *after* you update the eclipse ADT plugin</s>

This is only possible **after** you have installed SDK tools rev 20. So re-open your SDK manager

Comment: As i mention in my question "i already have rev 9 of Android Support"

Comment: @AndroidCoader Well my update worked, have you closed n reopened adb , adt , sdkm, eclipse, your computer etc. Also have you got the SDK directory set in eclipse>preferences>Android

Comment: Installing the update is not the issue, it installs OK or was already there in the first place. The problem is that even though rev 9 is present, the wizard says 'you must have version 8 to proceed'. Someone has put a '==' condition in the code where it should have been a '>='

Comment: @NickT LOL happens sometime. Google also have some micro bugs so our codes also :)