# Issue creating android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse, android ADT and SDK and did every thing, but when I create a project  by following these steps:

Android Application project

Project Name

Package Name

Create Activity

New Blank Activity

and hitting next, I get this error shown below.what is causing this issue. [image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears you need to install the ASL. Try clicking `Install/Upgrade`.

Comment: Try restarting your computer and then try clicking `Check Again` when you get to this screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are two buttons **install/update**  and **check again** right

you must click **install/update** to finish your set up

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the Android SDK Manager and download/install 'Android Support'

Comment: On the toolbar look for a little box with a down arrow and an Android peeking out of the top.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is,

> The correct workaround is to use the SDK Manager and remove any
>   existing Support or Compatibility library then reinstall it from the
>   SDK Manager.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262706/726863) answer already answered.