# why i failed to run android in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb, eclipse-adt

it is a bit confusing that adb.exe is just in the right path ...

the version of eclipse i use is Build id:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722
```

my adt version is：

```
    20.0.3
```

the error message i get from android console is as follows, why the error happens?

```
[2012-09-26 12:17:40 - android] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-09-26 12:17:42 - android] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-09-26 12:17:48 - android] ------------------------------
[2012-09-26 12:17:48 - android] Android Launch!


[2012-09-26 12:17:48 - android] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2012-09-26 12:17:48 - android] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-09-26 12:17:48 - android] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\Tools\sdk-tools\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

what's more, once i start android emulator, i can find it using:

```
  adb devices
```

but i cannot find it in adt's device view, why?

Comment: Restart your eclipse its not error.

Comment: with the same error, also i have tried adb kill-server, adb start-server, useless...

Comment: Can you try to run your eclipse as an admin user? Right click on eclipse launch icon and launch as admin user. See what happens now.

Comment: is adb.exe present under D:\Tools\sdk-tools\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11262706/582571 check this link. it may be useful for you. I think you are getting the error because of library support.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i expected that you will be get help from this [How can i update my ADT in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse) . Please try this. May be you will be succeed  your problem. Best of Luck!