# Not able to create Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm not able to create a new android project in eclipse.
Whenever I try to create one & reach last screen of the wizard & hit finish button, a empty project (just folder structure) project with the same name gets created in navigator window but the wizard does not go away.

It still has that finish button & nothing happens on clicking it again.
The project created in navigator should have at-least few files for me to start working on it.

Any help?

I'm using eclipse indigo on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: did you add plugin in eclipse

Comment: yes that is there ... sample projects are getting created & they run fine in emulator

Comment: Is it just empty in eclipse of folders are empty as well in your file explorer ?

Comment: empty folders in file explorer also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to Use Following Suggestion i'm Not Sure But Might Help you.

1 ) **`Just go with default launcher image (blue smiley) instead of customizing it and it should work.`**

2) If you have installed support library>8 Still get the error msg

```
-->Delete the support library from the SDK manager
-->Create a new project & install the support library by clicking on "Install / Upgrade"
```

also [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262471/install-dependencies-not-resolved-in-adt-r20/11262706#11262706) for More Information.

Hope it will Some How Help you.

Comment: tried that but still now luck ... getting same errors again  ...   eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

Error
Fri Nov 30 16:24:12 IST 2012
Failed to load properties file for project 't5app'

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to improper instalation..Can you specify what the message/error, it showing when you click finish on your project creation..?
else try to install eclipse again in someother location..
[Installation steps-click here](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2011/06/how-to-install-the-android-sdk-and-eclipse-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Failed to load properties file for project 't5app'

Comment: Failed to finish PrecompilerBuilder#startupOnInitialize()

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, I had this problem and I ended up reinstalling eclipse and the sdk, but I instead of installing them separately, I installed bundle:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html
and I don't get have this problem anymore.