# Not able to create new Project with ADT version 21 (creates empty project)

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I've just download the Android Developer Tools **v21.1.0-569685** for **Mac**. I'm unable to create an android application project and get an empty project whenever I follow the steps below.

1. I've opened Eclipse.
2. And used the menu `File` -> `New` -> `Android Application Project`.
3. I enter `TestApp` as the name.
4. Then click next through all pages leaving the default options.
5. When I get to the last page (`Next` is Disabled and `Finish` becomes enabled) I click `Finish`. There's a bit of activity when this happens and I can see a project added to the Package Explorer in the background, but the window with the `Finish` button stays there. If I cancel out of the android application wizard the project it created is still present by it's empty (see screenshot). [image]

Note: I've attempted the solutions at [Not able to create new Project with ADT version 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259069/not-able-to-create-new-project-with-adt-version-20) with no joy.

Comment: If I download the same version and run it on WinXP, I do not have the same problem.

Comment: This happens on Mac 10.8.2, but I've just tried the same download and process on Mac 10.7.5 and the same issue was not present.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was another Java application had installed different versions of some .jar files into `/Library/Java/Extensions`. .jar files on that path are automatically loaded. Removing the .jar files from that path resolved the problem.

In my case the problem was specifically the Australian Governments AUSKey software that installs .jars into the Extensions directory.

The solution was reported here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54452.