# Android Support Library not being detected by wizard - Cannot create MasterDetailFlow

Tags: android, eclipse, wizard, android-support-library, eclipse-adt

I have created a few projects with the MasterDetailFlow using API 11 earlier.
I needed to add LoginActivity so I downloaded the needed SDKs and updated the SDK tools to rev 22.2

http://prntscr.com/1rzb9j

Now that it is updated, when I use the wizard to create a new MasterDetailFlow project, or when adding an Activity template such as LoginActivity (to my previously created project having MasterDetailFlow layout) it says that the Android Support Library is not available or is outdated.

http://prntscr.com/1rzbc5

> This template depends on the Android Support library, which is either not installed, or the template depends on a more recent version than the one you have installed.
>
> Required version: 8
>
> Installed version: 18

I have tried Uninstalling and reinstalling via the Wizard, to no avail
(as advised here [Not able to create new Project with ADT version 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259069/not-able-to-create-new-project-with-adt-version-20/11262604#11262604))
After I uninstall and run the wizard- the Installed version shows "not available" and thus I click on "Install/Upgrade"; where it installs and shows that the Installed version is 18 but the next and finish buttons are disabled, and "Check Again" does nothing.

I have also tried manually installing also, going back to version 8, even then it says:

> Required version: 8
>
> Installed version: 8

Here too, the next button is disabled, and check again does nothing.

I repeated the above said solutions many times, and no luck. I am thinking it might be something else that is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues when create new android application project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c55

> Hi everyone,
>
> This one is my bad. I was in the middle of changing the dependency
> system used by the templates and a transient state got picked up into
> this tools build. The templates have settled in the AOSP master
> branch.
>
> I've attached a snapshot of the current Activities templates.
> Replacing your sdk/tools/templates/activities folder with the contents
> of this zip should resolve this issue.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience.

Download the given file and replace it with the templates, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try google app inventor for creating android applications. Its easier and lot more simple.

Answer (score 0):

install the platforms and extras in the sdk better install all there is to install in the sdk